# Windows 2008: setspn -L domain\account returns Invalid DN Syntax

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

As the title indicates, on Windows 2008 R2, use of `SETSPN -L domain\account` returns `Ldap Error(0x22 -- Invalid DN Syntax): ldap_search_s`

What little information I could find, says the `domain\account` may contain an 'invalid' character in its name. However, I do not have sufficient privileges on the domain or forest to change the account's information in Active Directory.

Is there anything else I should check or might be able to do to get a list of SPN's registered to the account?

Comment: I have a domain account with a `$` symbol in it, i.e. `DOMAIN\$zz_anaccount` and I also get the error. I have not found out how I can 'escape' it though. I certainly can't change the name of it. Quite annoying.

Comment: Related: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/just-another-odd-error/ba-p/243123

Answer (score 2):

What I have discovered about this error message is if the DN has an extra comma in it, you may have issues listing the SPNs.

For example, I had these problems with a DN CN=Reporting\, Domain,OU=Users,DC=domain,dc=com. I had to rename/reformat the account so that it appeared as CN=Domain Reporting,OU=Users,DC=domain,dc=com. Then my problem went away.